# Using a feature branch with Berkshelf

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, berkshelf

I'm trying to use a feature branch to test some functionality in a current cookbook I am working on. Normally I would point to the master branch like so:

`cookbook 'elasticsearch', github: 'account-name/cookbook-elasticsearch'`

Is there any way to point to a feature branch? Has anyone had any success doing that before?

Thank-you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright y'all. I just figured this out, but I thought I should share since it wasn't completely obvious from the [docs](http://berkshelf.com/).

So you just need to grab the commit id from the commit that you want to use in berks.

For example in my case I did

`cookbook "elasticsearch", github:"account-name/elasticsearch", tag:"a27dr77g4f97420cd1a69282ce6177a2b95befda"`

and vola!

Comment: why not using the branch name as mentionned in the doc (just above groups at bootom of the page)? This kind of reference is more for a specific commit than a branch. For your case `cookbook 'elasticsearch', github: 'D1plo1d/cookbook-elasticsearch', branch: "fixes"` should do (branch is an alias to tag, more meaningfull in this case)